# How can I see the history log of non-mapreduce job in yarn

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have configured the history server of yarn. But it looks like it can only help me to see the history log of mapreduce jobs. I still could not see the logs of non-mapreduce job. How can I see the history log of non-mapreduce job ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a work in progress. Please see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-321 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-1530.